# How to create child process for particular function?

Tags: node.js

my requirement is to read 10,000 records(each nearly 1MB size) and save data to MongoDB in node js application. For this i have written one function to do this. Due to this i have some impact on node js application performance. When i am reading node docs i found that child process for a particular js file. Is this correct? if Not, Please suggest me how to create a separate process to only do this and then it should be killed. If Correct, will  the performance of main node process degrade?

Comment: Use "Cluster" node module so you can create a worker for each function call. Each worker runs in separate child process.

Comment: You can just create a new node.js app that has a specific function and then launch that as a child process using the [child process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) with some input data and it will run to completion and then give you some output and exit on its own.  Or you can create a continuous process that you communicate with using some form of IPC to send it data (like a webSocket) and it then sends you back a result.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. And you are making me to think in different posibilities. Thanks alot